# SignalR not working in Android App (with Nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: android, nginx, signalr, signalr-hub

We have a mobile application (iOS & Android) that makes real-time communication with our API through SignalR.

There is one single case where the SignalR Hubs were not functioning in a platform where Nginx was used as a reverse proxy. We found and applied the "X-Accel-Buffering: no" http header solution as defined in https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/10827.

Now the problem is gone in iOS Devices, but not in Android. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?